# In adbtask_settings Oracle Table what is the meaning of INTERVAL and max_run_time column?

Tags: oracle

In adbtask_settings Oracle Table what is the meaning of INTERVAL and max_run_time column? This table is being used for AUTOTask job execution so I want to know the significance of these columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column in table adbtask_settings.

Interval=180 -- it means every 180 seconds, Autotask will try to schedule your task.

max_run_time=900 -- it means if client task already run for 1800 seconds but not yet finish, a timeout error will be signaled to interrupt client task
which means that is the maximal runtime allowed.

If you want test these functionalities then you use below proc to change the value and check the job execution time in below SELECT query:

```
execute DBMS_ADBTASK_ADMIN.MODIFY_ADBTASK_SETTINGS ('Auto Compress','INTERVAL',180);
execute DBMS_ADBTASK_ADMIN.MODIFY_ADBTASK_SETTINGS ('Auto Compress','MAX RUN TIME',900);

select run_duration from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where job_name='ORA$_ATSK_AUTOCOMP' order by actual_start_date desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer and let modify the value of INTERVAL and MAX_RUN_TIME to verify it.